# How to capture request id inside a lambda function in a chalice app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chalice

I am having a chalice app which exposes some urls backed by api gateway and lambda function.
What I want is to log the request id with each and every log msg for debugging purposes.
Below is how my code looks like.

```
@app.route('/instrument', methods=['GET'])
@logging_and_error_handling()
def get_instrument_value():
 // some code
 // logger.log() Here I want to put the request id.
```

I can see that request id is getting logged in the cloudwatch by default. I want to use the same request id. How do I capture it inside my method ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aws_request_id` in the context object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html